# How do i obtain data from view to my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside my `view` I have declared a `variable` like this:

```
<span>{{myVariable = 25}}</span>
```

Now how do I obtain the value of `myVariable` in the `controller`?

`alert($scope.myVariable)` is `undefined.`

I know this is **quirky** but just want to know how to `declare variables` in view and 
get the same in `controller`.

Any way I could do the same using `ng-init` ?

Comment: That is not the correct use of {{ }}. It is used to bind a expression to an html element. What you are trying to do there will be reevaluated every time there is a digest loop. If you want to initialize a variable just do it in the controller. Please explain why do you need to initialize a variable in the template.

Answer (score 1):

For the described scenario you could use ngInit
However it would make more sense to initialize your variable in the controller if it is where you need it. This is is how you could do it from the view using ngInit:

```
<span ng-init="myVariable = 25">{{myVariable }}</span>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: no I need to declare and initialize in my view itself.

Comment: Now if i alert myVariable i get undefined.

Comment: If you alert the variable before it is defined that May happens try using $scope.$watch('myVar', function(newValue){ alert(newValue);}

Answer (score 1):

You cant get the value from the controller in onload. But you can get like this (in onDemand)

```
$scope.click function() {
    alert($scope.myVariable)
}
```

Comment: That is not what i want.

Comment: you mean you need to get the value when the controller gets initialized. Am right?

Comment: Yeah. When i console.log the variable i need to be able to access it